# Performing updates/overwrite to tables in Azure SQL Database from Databricks

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, databricks

In Azure Databricks the table is already created in the Azure SQL warehouse and I'd like to perform an update to the existing in the azure sql database or overwrite it's contents when my job runs

I am able to append but I am facing issues to perform update/overwrite for performing etl. 
I have tried the below and but it drops the table and tries to recreate with set of new records which is not what I want.

```
def insupd(df,tabname):
df.write.mode("overwrite") \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", jdbcUrl) \
.option("dbtable", tabname) \
.option("user",jdbcUsername) \
.option("password", jdbcPassword) \
.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
.save()
 return True
```

Need to know how I can perform the update/overwrite in my case. Also please let me know require libraries to import.

Comment: you can use merge table using below syntax `MERGE INTO logs
USING updates
ON logs.uniqueId = updates.uniqueId
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT *`  [link](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html)

Comment: Thanks Praveen, I was trying that but how will I post the ultimate result to the database. Also the merge table refers to the actual tables in the database ?

In that case can you please share exactly what are the steps I need to use(which library to impost, how to provide DB credentials). I have tables in the Azure SQL database which I have insert/update. I got the merge syntax but I dont know the exact implementation steps to achieve the same.

Comment: sudipta please go throught this link [link](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html) it will give details information how to do update/overwrite sql database . give me comment it you still facing any issue.

Comment: overwrite all its contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the truncate option set to true to your write:

```
.option("truncate", True)
```

See this article explaining this: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/savemode.overwrite-trap-rdbms-apache-spark-sql/read

and from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html):

> This is a JDBC writer related option. When SaveMode.Overwrite is
>   enabled, this option causes Spark to truncate an existing table
>   instead of dropping and recreating it. This can be more efficient, and
>   prevents the table metadata (e.g., indices) from being removed.
>   However, it will not work in some cases, such as when the new data has
>   a different schema. It defaults to false. This option applies only to
>   writing.